# Visual C++ 2015 express: _stat not working on Windows XP

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Running the following [example for _stat from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx) compiled with Visual C++ 2015 Express using `v140_xp` as `Platform Toolset` (target Win32) runs normally on Windows 7 but not on Windows XP on several machines I tested.

```
// crt_stat.c
// This program uses the _stat function to
// report information about the file named crt_stat.c.

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
  struct _stat buf;
  int result;
  char timebuf[26];
  char* filename = "crt_stat.c"; // Absolute paths like "D:\\crt_stat.c" produce the same behaviour.
  errno_t err;

  // Get data associated with "crt_stat.c":
  result = _stat( filename, &buf );

  // Check if statistics are valid:
  if ( result != 0 )
  {
    perror( "Problem getting information" );
    switch ( errno )
    {
    case ENOENT:
      printf( "File %s not found.\n", filename );
      break;
    case EINVAL:
      printf( "Invalid parameter to _stat.\n" );
      break;
    default:
      /* Should never be reached. */
      printf( "Unexpected error in _stat.\n" );
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // Output some of the statistics:
    printf( "File size     : %ld\n", buf.st_size );
    printf( "Drive         : %c:\n", buf.st_dev + 'A' );
    err = ctime_s( timebuf, 26, &buf.st_mtime );
    if ( err )
    {
      printf( "Invalid arguments to ctime_s." );
      return 1;
    }
    printf( "Time modified : %s", timebuf );
  }
}
```

Windows 7 output:

```
File size     : 6
Drive         : D:
Time modified : Tue Sep  8 10:06:57 2015
```

Windows XP output:

```
Problem getting information: Invalid argument
Invalid parameter to _stat.
```

And yes crt_stat.c is located in the executables directory which also is the CWD.

Is this a Bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you test your example with an absolute path?

Comment: Just tested it with the absolute path "D:\\crt_stat.c". The results are the same. Win7 is fine, WinXP is not.

Comment: MSDN: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1557168/wstat64-returns-1-on-xp-always - sounds like a VS2015 bug

Comment: Maybe `_fstat()` will work (I doubt it)

Comment: @Petesh Damn, quite a bummer! Hope they will fix it very soon. Thanks for the help.

@SimonKraemer `_fstat()` also does not work.

Comment: It looks like there are a handful of issues with `vc140_xp`.  Sadly, I wouldn't imagine that they'll be pushing to fix this as a high priority, since XP is past end of life.  If `GetFileAttributesEx` isn't an option for portability reasons, you may want to consider targeting an older version instead of waiting.

Comment: `GetFileAttributesEx` is a valid option. We already started replacing all occurences of `_stat` etc. with it in out code base.

Comment: We've fixed this bug and are working on getting the fix into an update.  When we have the details locked down, we'll resolve the Connect bug with more information.  Thanks.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Great to hear! Thanks for the information. Looking forward to the update.

Comment: What happens if you define _USE_32BIT_TIME_T. Forces the code to use _stat32 instead of _stat64.

Comment: @cup All variants of the stat functions (including the fstat functions) use one common implementation and all are thus afflicted by this bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it is a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1557168/wstat64-returns-1-on-xp-always) in the runtime. Right now (2015-09-09) the fix is not yet available in an update, but probably will be soon. A workaround is to use `GetFileAttributesEx` instead.

Comment: I was able to write a shim by adapting some code from ReactOS that implements stat using GetFileAttributesEx. https://github.com/mirror/reactos/blob/master/reactos/lib/sdk/crt/stdio/stat64.c

Answer (score 0):

The bug is solved on Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 Update 1

I solved the problem by installing that update form here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49984

Comment: Even update1, with static link c++ runtime lib (Multithread Debug), the stat still always failed with invalid parameter