# Windows XP runtime issues with path spaces when compiled with XP toolset in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10, windows-xp

I am using Visual Studio 15 2017 with the v141_xp toolset to compile a Win32 app for Windows XP.  The app will run fine on both Windows 10 and XP, but running some Windows API commands like `_chdir` and `_mkdir` (or `CreateDirectory`) don't seem to work right: The directory is not created or, in the case of `_chdir` the application doesn't change its working directory.

I thought the issue was paths with spaces in the name, but I'm not entirely sure this is the case.  I properly use `\\` and `"\""` in strings where needed, but when manipulating paths like this, it seems to either work in XP, but not 10, or it works in 10, but not XP.

I wish the code to work properly on both.  Are there other compatibility issues that I'm missing?

Thanks.

**More Info**

I am compiling with /MTd 'Mult-threaded Debug' because of portability requirements.  It's looking like this may be some issue with CRT being compiled in.

Comment: How does it not work?  Could we get a [mcve]?

Comment: Where in particular are you trying to create these directories? It could be related to "Standard User" vs. "Admin" rights.

Comment: I'm always creating in standard user folders.  I think this is related to a number of issues introduced with a refactor of CRT code.  I just fixed one based on stat shown here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/32452777/2079522

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the bug was with `stat` and described here a little more here:

[Visual C++ 2015 express: _stat not working on Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32452777/2079522)

My application was using this existence test for a file or directory, which has been a convenient cross-platform solution for many years:

```
return (stat(path.c_str(), &st) == 0);
```

But if you are compiling for Windows XP using a newer toolset, `stat` is now broken and you have to use the Windows API like:

```
return (GetFileAttributes(path.c_str()) != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES);
```